# Postgres is adding a space at the beginning and end of all fields

Tags: postgresql, psql

SLES 12 SP3
Postgres 10.8

I have duplicated a table to migrate data from a DB2 instance. The fields are all of type CHAR, VARCHAR, or TIMESTAMP. I originally tried to use \COPY to pull the data in from a pipe delimited file. But, it put a space at the beginning and end of all of the fields, even if this caused the field to be longer than it is defined. I found a claim online that this was a known issue with \COPY. At that point, I dropped the table, used sed and some other tools to convert the pipe delimited data into an SQL INSERT statement. I again had a leading and trailing space in every field.

There are a lot of columns but as an example of what I have follows:

```
FLD1  CHAR(6) PRIMARY KEY
FLD2  VARCHAR(8)
FLD3  TIMESTAMP
```

I am using the short form of INSERT.

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('123456', '12345678', '2021-01-01 12:34:56');
```

But when I do a SELECT, I get (note the leading and trailing spaces):

```
 123456 | 12345678 | 2021-01-01 12:34:56 |
```

I would point out that the first two fields are now longer than they are defined by 2 characters.

Does anyone how I might fix this?

Comment: Are you using `psql`? Then this is simply a formatting thing to make the output more readable. Btw: [don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Comment: `\copy` - if used correctly - will not add those spaces: https://i.imgur.com/0UdjolZ.png

Comment: What does LENGTH() tell you about these fields? It's rather unlikely that COPY adds spaces, we use it many times an hour, for years, and I've never seen this behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I am using psql. Is there a way to prevent it from adding the spaces? All of the rows I am using char on have the same length.

Comment: Could you show us the result from this query: SELECT length(FLD1) as l_FLD1
 , length(FLD2) as l_FLD2
 , length(FLD3::text) as l_FLD3
FROM your_table_name;

Comment: LENGTH returns the correct size for the fields.

Comment: By the way, a TIMESTAMP with additional spaces would be an invalid value and result in an error message.

Comment: Thats because you now measure the length of a value and you're not staring at the presentation in a specific software tool. psql in your case. Use another tool and you will get a different presentation.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

Comment: If it really bothers you then in `psql` do `\pset format unaligned` that will remove the formatting spaces. I'm guessing you will prefer the default, which is `\pset format aligned`. For more information on formatting `psql` output see here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and search for `\pset [ option`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The -A argument to psql gives me the desired result.

Comment: Never trust an online claim when you have a manual that can help you to find how it really works ;-)

Comment: `\copy` or `copy to stdout` is much better suited to generated a delimited output to a file